# Don't show preview window for Raspistill?

Tags: raspicam, raspivid

I am using the following command to capture and write jpegs to a tmp directory which end up getting streamed over the network

```
raspistill -w 640 -h 480 -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th 0:0:0 &
```

When I execute this command a large image preview comes up on screen which I cannot seem to dismiss without killing the raspistill process.

How can I use raspistill without showing the preview window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use it with -n flag or --nopreview flag. Ie, your command should look like this.

```
raspistill -w 640 -h 480 -n -q 5 -o /tmp/stream/pic.jpg -tl 100 -t 9999999 -th 0:0:0 &
```

For more raspistill related options, check out [this](http://www.modmypi.com/blog/raspberry-pi-camera-board-raspistill-command-list).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it's `--nopreview`, one word?

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for pointing out. :-) it should be without spaces like you said. Edited.